# Equilateral triangle inscribed in parabola

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Count how many parabolas with integer coeficients, $y=ax^2+bx+c$ can have an equilateral triangle with vertices on the intersection of the parabola and on the x and y axis.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and/or are closed.

Comment: To start, observe that given that one of the vertices is on the y axis, the two roots of the polynomial have to be symmetrical.

Comment: the roots are always simetrical, and that leads to the triangle having 2 equal sides, that was obvious

Comment: I got one where the y axis point is the maxima/minima point, but that only gives me 2 parabolas, and the supposed answer is 4 parabolas

Comment: Did you count downward parabolas?

Comment: $a=\pm1,\ \pm3$.

Comment: yeah, could you explain how you got there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, you got $b=0$. The position of the three points are then $$\left(-\sqrt{-\frac ca},0\right),\left(+\sqrt{-\frac ca},0\right),(0,c)$$
Then the distance between the intersections with $x$ axis is $$d=2\sqrt{-\frac ca}$$
The distance between one of the intersection with $x$ axis and the intersection with $y$ axis is $$d=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{-\frac ca}\right)^2+c^2}$$
Equating the squares of these distances we get $$c^2=-3\frac ca$$
Obviously $c=0$ is not a good solution, since the equilateral triangle will reduce to the origin. Then $$a=-\frac 3c$$
Since both $a$ and $c$ are integers, it means that the possible $c$ values $\pm1,\pm3$ and the corresponding $a$ values are $\mp3,\mp1$.